# Internal Server Error in Magento

Tags: database, magento

I just uploaded my website on server and now it is showing this error

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

What is this error about ..?
and how i solve this error ..?

URL : celebrityjackets.co.uk

Comment: Check error log files

Comment: Hope this will help you .http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

Answer (score 0):

This could relate to an error in your `.htaccess`.
Try to rename it for a short time.

Then check your logfiles for errors related to missing directives in your vhost-configuration.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride for more info.